# Ethernet transfer slow from Cyclone V FPGA DDR3 memory

Tags: c, linux, sockets, fpga, ethernet

We are using CycloneV in our project, FPGA will write data to DDR using AXI bus and our application needs to send the data out using Ethernet. We benchmark our Ethernet throughput using iperf and it can achieve a speed of about 700Mbps. When we test our application throughput, the result we are getting is just 300Mbps. We need to know why is our transfer slow compared to iperf benchmark.

DDR3 memory is reserved at boot time for FPGA direct access

Can you suggest why is my ethernet transfer slower than iperf benchmarked data (~700Mbps) and how can I increase my throughput?

```
if ((fd = open("/dev/mem", (O_RDWR | O_SYNC))) == -1)
{
    printf("ERROR: could not open /dev/mem/ \n");
}

pMem = mmap(NULL, SDRAM_64_SPAN, (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE), MAP_SHARED, fd, SDRAM_64_BASE);

if (pMem == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf("ERROR: mmap failed\n");
}
```

Client socket running in the SoC which sends about 1 Mbyte of data and server is on PC which is continuously receiving the data

Client code which is called only once

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int n = 1024*2*1024;
unsigned int m = sizeof(n);
if ((setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &n, m) < 0)
{
    printf("ERROR: Setting socket send buffer size\n");
}

int opt = 1;
if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &opt, sizeof(opt)) > 0)
{
    printf("ERROR: Unable to set TCP no delay\n");
}

if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
{
    printf("ERROR: connecting to server\n");
}

int flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0);
int newflags = flags | (int) O_NONBLOCK;
if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, newflags) < 0)
{
    printf("ERROR: setting non blocking mode\n");
}
```

On each data transfer, the client keeps sending the data as follows

```
int len = 128*256*4*8;
int r = sendall(sock, (char *)pMem, &len);

if (r == -1)
{
    printf("ERROR: sending data\n");
}

int sendall(int s, char *buf, int *len)
{
    int total = 0;
    int bytesleft = *len;
    int n;

    while (total < *len)
    {
        n = 0;
        n = send(s, buf + total, bytesleft, 0);
        if ((n == -1) && ((errno == EWOULDBLOCK) || (errno == EAGAIN)))
        {
            n = 0;
            usleep(5);
        }
        else
        {
            if (n < 0)
            {
                printf("ERROR: sending data\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }

    *len = total;

    return n==-1?-1:0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using non-blocking mode on the socket? That `usleep(5)` seems arbitrary. Why not just run in blocking mode and let the kernel do what it is good at?

Comment: Tried blocking mode as well, the throughput is still around 300 Mbps.

Comment: Also, is this dual-port RAM? If not it seems that the processor and FPGA will be in frequent contention for the memory. Have you measured how fast you can simply read from the memory mapping?

Comment: This is not dual port RAM. But the ethernet transfer starts only after DMA has finished the writes to the RAM. 

I tried reading 1 Mbyte from this memory to local memory using memcpy. This takes around 16ms.

Comment: Can you edit your code? This looks like a typo (unbalanced parentheses): `if ((fd = open("/dev/mem", (O_RDWR | O_SYNC) == -1)`

Comment: I suspect you are testing stale `errno` values in `sendall`. You should only check `errno` if `send` returns `-1`.

Comment: The looping in `sendall` looks too complicated and wrong as it doesn't break out of the inner `do while` loop on error. Try: `while (total < *len) { n = send(s, buf + total, bytesleft, 0); if (n == -1) { if ((errno == EWOULDBLOCK) || (errno == EAGAIN)) { n = 0; usleep(5); } else { printf("ERROR: sending data\n"); break; } total += n; bytesleft -= n; }`

Comment: Thanks @IanAbbott I have updated the code to fix the bugs. Still the throughput is about 280-300 Mbps. Any ideas on how can the ethernet throughput be increased?

Comment: What percentage of time does it spend doing nothing in the `usleep` calls? Have you tried using `poll` or `select`?

Comment: @IanAbbott, if I use the memory buffer declared in my code as follows, I get throughput as 700 Mbps

```C
char buffer[128*256*4*8];
r = sendall(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```
There is some issue with using mmap as I have used which caused the data reads from pMem to be slower. But I need to use it as FPGA needs to have direct access to DDR3 memory. I am looking for ways which can be used to reduce the time to read from the pMem which is mmap'ed to the area in DDR3 memory where DMA is writing the data.

Comment: I believe you have a hardware design issue which can't be fixed in software. Forget about the Ethernet sending for now, and focus on how fast you can read data from that memory mapped area. 1 MiB in 16ms is only 62.5 MiB/sec. If you can't read from the memory any faster than that, then how can you expect to send data from it faster? You haven't told us how exactly the system works, but again I suspect contention in hardware (bus or DDR controller).

Comment: Is it possible to measure the throughput of sending the `mmap`ed buffer contents without the FPGA writing to the memory at the same time?

Comment: @IanAbbott, I created another mmap region where FPGA is not writing the data. The time it took to read 1 Mbyte from this region to a local buffer using memcpy was about 4.2ms. And the ethernet throughput went up to 500 Mbps. I through we can save some time by avoiding memcpy into a localbuffer if we directly send the data from the mmap pointer over ehternet we can increase the throughput. But if we try to avoid memcpy and do direct transfer, we get only about 420Mbps ethernet throughput.

Comment: 2 questions: (1) Why is memcpy helping in ethernet throughput? (2) Why is reading from memory where FPGA is writing is slower (about 4 times - 16ms vs 4ms) and can we increase this speed?

A similar question was asked earlier [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179097/mmap-very-slow-when-using-o-sync], but I have no clue about dma_mmap_coherent etc or how can we achieve 700 Mbps throughput by transferring data where FPGA is writing.

Comment: Linux is reserved only 800M from DDR3 and rest of the memory in DDR3 is reserved for FPGA using the instructions given here [https://forum.rocketboards.org/t/how-to-reserve-ddr3-memory-region-for-fpga-direct-access/162]

Comment: (1) Perhaps `send` reads the source data more than once (though I'm not sure why, since it copies the data into socket buffers (SKBs) anyway) which would make a difference when the source data is in non-cached memory. (2) I don't know, but there is bound to be some contention. I guess the burst length used by the DMA master has some influence on this. ASIDE: DMA coherent memory initialized by `dma_init_coherent_memory` in "kernel/dma/coherent.c" is mapped as write-combined. Not sure if that makes a difference.